# Node OracleDB Error: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

Error when using OracleDB with Error "The specified procedure could not be found".Node Install OracleDB went through fine.
Steps executed for build are

- Installed Visual Studio 2017 Visual C++ 14.0
- Downloaded and followed oracle instant client and sdk, OCI_BIN and OCI_INC added
- npm install npm@latest
- npm install node-gyp -g ( before this step removed c:\users\.node-gyp
- npm install oracledb
- OCI_INC_DIR Points to 'C:\Oracle\instantclient\lib\msvc'
- OCI_LIB_DIR
  Points to 'C:\Oracle\instantclient\include' npm done was for
  oracledb@1.13.1

Error when running the code with `node app.js`
/app.js contents

````
var oracle = require("oracledb");
console.log(oracle)

Windows 8.1 x64 64 Bit OS
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@6.3.1 | win32 | x64
6.3.1
node 6.3.1
npm 5.3.0

D:\test\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:38
    throw err;
    ^
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\\?\D:\test\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> D:\test\\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb
.js:35:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```
````

The same error when using strongloop /loopback CLI.
Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Check the paths involved.   Check you have the VS redistributable (see Instant Client download page instructions). You could do worse that testing out node-oracledb v2, which has improved some error messages: these may give a hint to your problem.  It's currently not production, so install from GitHub with `npm install oracle/node-oracledb.git#dev-2.0`

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/747

Comment: Resolved:  Issue with c:\oracle\oracleinstant client not being at the start of  PATH variables

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Issue with c:\oracle\oracleinstant client not being at the start of PATH variables on windows

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem.
This error is related with oracle client.

Possible troubles:

- Wrong PATH env. variable
- Wrong OCI_INC_DIR and OCI_LIB_DIR paths
- Wrong version of oracle client (32-bit vs 64-bit). Version must be the same as node version

My problem was the version of the oracle client, so i installed another one. I also fixed PATH variable and OCI_INC_DIR & OCI_LIB_DIR paths to the new oracle client, but still no success.

The problem went away after I deleted both oracle clients, and installed only the one I needed.

Conclusion: Even though you specify the paths to the correct oracle driver, the installer can pick the other one, so be careful.